# PostgreSQL ODBC driver not showing up in Control Panel (Data Sources)

Tags: postgresql, 64-bit, odbc, controlpanel

I installed [psqlODBC](http://psqlodbc.projects.postgresql.org/) and when I go to Control Panel -> Data Sources (ODBC) I don't see the Postgres driver installed.

I rebooted, still nothing.

I then noticed that if I launch this control panel applet from the file `c:\WINDOWS\system32\odbccp32.cpl` the drivers suddenly appear!

This happens on an XP 64 bit machine.

I can't really explain why this is, or what the implications of this are.

When launching from the Control Panel, rundll32's command line is:

```
"rundll32.exe" shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL "c:\WINDOWS\system32\odbccp32.cpl",
```

(this data is from Process Explorer)

When launching from `odbccp32.cpl` the command line is:

```
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe" C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ODBCCP32.CPL",@0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I installed this driver the other day and it appeared in the Data Sources straight away, no reboot needed.  I didn't do anything out of the ordinary either.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question because it belongs on server-fault obviously has no understanding of what ODBC is. Next time, please ignore the tag.

Comment: +1 I just loved to find this question related to the same problem I have had the whole day with my 32-bits DB2 Data Center Client driver on my Win7 64-bits system. It's a shame I can't upvote more! Thanks for asking this question! =)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Did you perhaps install a 32 bit driver?
The applet starts the 64-bit version of the odbc admin tool, odbcad32.exe. Try running the 32-bit version in %systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64\odbcad32.exe.

Registry redirection makes this a bit of a headache, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976 for more information.

Comment: Seriously? The 64-bit version is called `odbcad32` and the 32-bit version is in the `SysWoW64` directory?

Comment: Yup :-) They're both called odbcad32.exe, WoW64 stands for Windows-on-Windows 64.

Comment: +1 I would have liked to upvote this answer 10 times at least! I took the whole day turning around this problem with my freshly installed DB2 data center client drivers. The drivers are 32-bits, and my system is 64-bits. I just so happy to have found this answer, really! You saved my life! ;-) Thanks!

Comment: why would anyone be surprised?  this is coming from the company who got the world used to pressing the "start" button to "stop".

Comment: So if you are in Windows 7 64 bits open a command windows and run %windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe